# QNetworkAccessManager using rtsp link

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I need to check the RTSP link to the ipcamera is working or not using qt QNetworkAccessManager, right now I have below code and works fine with http link, where as if used rtps link I am getting `ProtocolUnknownError` for `reply->error()`

```
        QUrl url("rtsp://10.25.71.39:554/media/live/1/2");
        bool flag = false;

        int NETWORK_TIMEOUT_ =5000;
        QNetworkAccessManager networkmanager(this);
        QNetworkRequest req = QNetworkRequest(url);
        QNetworkReply *reply = networkmanager.get(req);
        QEventLoop loop;
        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));


        QTimer timer;
        connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
        timer.setSingleShot(true);
        timer.start(NETWORK_TIMEOUT_);


        loop.exec();

        if(timer.isActive()==false)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Network timeout No connection";
        }
        if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();
            flag =true;

       }
        return flag;
```

If I change the url to

`QUrl url("https://stackoverflow.com`");

I am getting success replay without any error.

Comment: Why don't you use link like: `QString("rtsp://%1:%2@10.25.71.39:554/media/live/1/2").arg(login, pass)` instead of using `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean in above code, can you please elaborate  it.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. Anyway, divide host and port from url and just use `QTcpSocket::connectToHost()` function with `QTcpSocket::waitForConnected()` function. If you're using Windows - do the same but with `QTcpSocket::error` signal or with `QTimer` if you do not want wait so long (30 sec).

Comment: QNetworkAccessManager does not support the rtsp protocol, you need to implement it yourself. See QNetworkAccessManager::supportedSchemes()